# PermissionDenied saving files via a pyinstaller executable, works in VS Code

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, printscreen

```
import os
import time
from PIL import ImageGrab

IMAGES_DIR = 'Estudos3\images'

FILENAME_FORMAT = 'screenshot_{}.png'

def take_screenshot():
    filename = FILENAME_FORMAT.format(int(time.time()))

    filepath = os.path.join(IMAGES_DIR, filename)

    ImageGrab.grab().save(filepath)

take_screenshot()
```

This python code takes a print of the screen and puts it in images, it works perfectly when I run it through vscode, the problem in question is that when I use PyInstaller to transform it into .exe and run it with ./ex.exe it displays an error of PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Estudos3\images\screenshot_1683919164.png'

Comment: well then either you don't have permission to write to that path or one of the intermediate folders doesn't exist

Answer (score 0):

I recommend checking bwoodsend answer here:

https://github.com/orgs/pyinstaller/discussions/5468

You may also need to run the command prompt as admin before running the executable depending on if the folder you are writing to has security permissions (e.g. only accessible by admin)

Comment: Ensure that your answer is complete enough that it still makes sense / helps people if the links break. "A sign pointing to where you can get apples is not an apple" is the way one of our classic [meta] posts describes it: similarly, a link to where someone can get answers is not an answer itself. Make sure what you're posting here is actually an answer, with steps someone can follow to solve their problem or an explanation of the problem that can be read and understood even if the absence of links.

Comment: ([Your answer is in another castle: When is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) is the classic meta post I was talking about -- turns out it's [meta.se] rather than [meta])